# Why new Date() constructor returns different timezone for the month February?

Tags: javascript, date

I have given unixTimeStamp objects given as below. `convertedMonthList` stores each unixTimeStamp as Date.Function `calculateUnixLocalTime` removes timezoneoffset from given date.

```
   const dateArray = [
      { Date: 1677628800000 },
      { Date: 1680307200000 },
      { Date: 1682899200000 },
    ];
    
    const convertedMonthList = dateArray.map(
      (el) => new Date(calculateUnixLocalTime(el.Date))
    );
            
   function calculateUnixLocalTime(value) {
      return value + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    }
```

When I printed convertedMonthList to the console you can see how dates are converted.Interestingly Feb. seems converted as GMT +5 the others are GMT +4 and location of this computer is GMT+4 why february is different?How to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Summer vs winter time!?

Comment: It's because of daylight saving time. Why does this matter though?

Comment: @Unmitigated It matters.If I would have one hour more added to Feb 28 which would be Mar 01.

Comment: So how do you want to handle daylight saving time?

Comment: yes I want that to be considered like GMT +4 as well

Comment: Nothing "added one hour", the local time at that date was simply shifted. You need to be VERY specific when trying to deal with time zones, why you want what output, etc.

Comment: The timestamps are in UTC, the dates aren't incorrect. For instance, the first one `1677628800000` is `Wed Mar 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000`

Comment: What even is "UnixLocalTime" in the first place? [Unix time is counting seconds since a fixed epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), it does not have time zones.

Comment: Don't ever use `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`! That gives you the timezone offset of your local system timezone at the current point in time. It's meaningless to apply this value to any other date than "right now".